# Changing the default foreign key constrain of a schema

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The default foreign key contrain of MariaDB `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` is `RESTRICT`.

However, in my schema, most foreign keys have `ON UPDATE` / `ON DELETE` set to `CASCADE`.

Although I appreciate the expliciting advertising of an occasional automatic deletation behavior, I find it annoying and slightly counter productive when the default behavior has to be explicitly typed for so many columns.

Is there an alternative to changing the default behavior per column, such as changing the default behavior of foreign keys `ON UPDATE` / `ON DELETE` constrains for an entire schema or table?

Comment: Bad idea.  When asking for `CASCADE`, you need to stop and ask "is cascade really appropriate" for each FK usage.

Comment: @RickJames Are you saying this is not implemented and this is the reason why? Or is this just your opinion?

Comment: Just my opinion.  (I am not a fan of FKs -- there are too many cases in these forums where people are stumbling over their limitations.)